# Calculate the length of a line feature and then add points at percentage length in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

The scenario is we have chopper pilots who are laying baits for wild dogs, pigs etc every X metres along a predetermined run length (multiple line features).

What I want to be able to do is determine where on the run they will be 25,50,75% through their flight run and they can determine the percentage of baits used so that they can be more accurate with their bait laying

Preferably within the arc toolbox so I can add to the existing modelbuilder project that automates the creation of flight paths etc.

Comment: I think you should look into linear referencing for this because you are describing point events along a route that can consist of multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend in ArcGIS,visit below links:
http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-create-points-polylines-arcpy/

http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/tools/configure-construction-tools/